# Flutter release to linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, flutter, dart

I have created a flutter app for Linux. but how to release flutter to Linux or windows.?

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done
```

Answer (score 9):

This is an official guide how to build and release production Flutter desktop app to Linux Snap Store: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/linux

If you just want to build e.g. Linux version and run it locally then try this:

```
flutter build linux
```

You'll find the executable in `build/linux/release/bundle` directory

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `flutter build` linux or windows and after the process finishes. You will find the files in build folder if you are building linux then you found a linux folder and same as windows
But remember both linux and windows are in developer preview so don't use it for production application.

Comment: what do you mean by `But remember both linux and windows are in developer preview so don't use it for production application.` ? so If I want to distribute the app only locally (i.e. using an executable file) then this is not the way to do it?

Comment: it's a old answer, now flutter desktop is stable so you can refer to flutter website for docs https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/windows

Answer (score -3):

To publish flutter for Linux you must have a system with Linux operating system. If you want to release for MAC, then you must have a MAC device. As the same for windows, you must have a windows os. So for Linux application publishing -  you must have to make sure that your operating system is Linux. Then you can build for Linux.

The building command is:

```
flutter build linux
```

#edited

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.